# Rails: Where should a web scraping method live?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

A Rails architecture question:

Basic problem is that I want to scrape several websites for products and bring them into the app to compare them.

I want to go and fetch the data, then create or update based on the response.
The controller will have the logic about whether to create or update the objects in the database, but **where should the scraping script live?**

It wants to get called by the controller and return a response. There will be one script for each external website and I can programmatically decide which script to call based on a stored variable.

Comment: `app/services/` is a good starting place to put things that don't belong elsewhere.

Comment: I think the only point anyone will really agree on is that this does not belong in your Model, View or Controller as they already have enough responsibilites. Instead create a separate class that you can test in isolation - for example a client class, job or service object.  There is also a [multitude of gems for web scraping](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Web_Content_Scrapers).

Answer (score 2):

I would just create a regular Ruby class that can scrape data and call that class from the controller.  You can put it in `app/services`, `app/classes`, `app/lib`, etc. I think all of those (anything in app/) will get picked up automatically by Rails.

So say you had a class `Scraper` with class methods of `.run` and `.data`:

```
class ScrapesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    scraper = Scraper.run(some_params)

    @scrape = Scrape.find_or_create_by(scraper.data)
  end
end
```